# WPF ItemsControl scrollbar

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, itemscontrol

Using `ItemsControl` to display a collection of items on a `Canvas`.
Probelm is that I can't see all the items on my screen (need to use `Scrollbars`), I've checked this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2009/06/09/stackpanel-dockpanel-and-scrolling-items.aspx) out and tried the same but it doesn't work for me, the `Scrollbar` is shown but disabled. My XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding MyCollection}>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        ....
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 9):

**`ItemsControl`** by default ***doesn't have ScrollViewer*** in it's Template unlike ListBox.

Get rid of the outer scrollViewer and set the Template of ItemsControl to contain ScrollViewer. Also, I don't see any usage of DockPanel when you already wrap ItemsControl inside Grid.

Change layout something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding MyCollection}>
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                        Focusable="False">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding 
                                               UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                ....
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```